# JavaScript: parseInt(string, 36) converts different strings to same number

Tags: javascript, parseint, bigint, string-conversion, base36

**I have an issue with string conversion:**

When using `parseInt(string[,radix])` like so:

```
BigInt(parseInt('something', 36))
```

it outputs: `80920602611116n`. with a different input like so:

```
BigInt(parseInt('somethink', 36))
```

it outputs: `80920602611120n`, which is something else of course.

However if it's a longer string, the output number is the same sometimes:

```
BigInt(parseInt('thisisactuallyadifferentsomething', 36))
BigInt(parseInt('thisisactuallyadifferentsomethink', 36))
```

this would output `1867697451648055638757226289961051507749359223570432n` for both, although they are different.

I know, that there is a limit for safe representation of integers, that's why I used BigInt, which has no limit.

I have to be able to differ strings of this size, while using BigInt to represent those.

Comment: parseInt is losing precision before BigInt

Comment: For some reason the Javascript BigInt type is relatively crippled compared to every other bigint type in the world.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [encode a big integer to base62](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61093432/encode-a-big-integer-to-base62/61852309#61852309), but replace the following base 62 digits...

```
var digits = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
```

...with the base 36 digits...

```
var digits = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
```

Hope this helps...