# How to encode binary data as any arbitrary text representation?

Tags: javascript, encoding, binary

I need a pair of functions for encoding binary data as any arbitrary text representation, and decoding it back

Say we have an ArrayBuffer of any size:

```
const buffer = new ArrayBuffer(1000)
```

Then we define a hexadecimal "lingo", and use it for encoding and decoding hex strings:

```
const lingo = "0123456789abcdef"

const text = encode(buffer, lingo)
const data = decode(text, lingo)
```

My goal is to define my own base48 "lingo", which omits vowels to avoid naughty words:

```
const lingo = "256789bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyzBCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXYZ"

const text = encode(buffer, lingo)
const data = decode(text, lingo)
```

How can we approach creating the algorithms for efficiently transforming data between arbitrary representations? Even though this strikes me as something quite fundamental, I'm having a hard time finding resources to help me with this task

Bonus points if you can think of any plausible naughty words without any vowels, I even took out the numbers that look like vowels!

I'm working in javascript, but I'd also like to understand the principals in general. Thanks!

Comment: If I were to create this algorithm, I would start with octal and hexadecimal before base 48 :) Seems like an intriguing math problem... but I'm not quite sure how to answer your question, except to maybe explain number representation in different bases. You would start by determining the base from the lingo, and partitioning the binary accordingly. Then you can loop through your data and map each partition to a character in your lingo. There may be examples of this for hexadecimal online. Good luck!

Comment: @dandeto — i'm quite stumped, but my thinking so far: because most "lingos" aren't a power of two in size, i think efficiency is impossible. i think i have to choose a "block size" of acceptable inefficiency, convert each block into a big number, and then encode that number with the lingo — the larger the block size, the more efficient, but any buffer smaller than the block size will be terribly inefficient — it's a trade off

Comment: Check BASE64 page on wikipedia (maybe also other BASExx pages). It explains how to split bytes into smaller bit sequences, then you use your array to encode such bit sequences (a BASE32 should works, with just consonant, upper and lower case). You cannot avoid bad words. Many languages do not have vowels (because our brain can interpolate them), and we use 1, 3, 0 as alternate vowels [and we may use j, v, and also as replacement. So maybe you can find 32 ASCII-non letters, which may be better (on automatic system, no transcription)

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi — i appreciate the warning, but i'm suspecting i might actually be able to eliminate bad words! first, as shown in the question, i did already remove numbers that look like letters. secondly, i'm okay with consonants smashed together that resemble bad words because it takes *a lot* of imagination, the bad words aren't there explicitly nor in widely-recognized l33t — given the base48 "lingo" i posted in my question, can you think of any naughty words that aren't too much of a stretch of the imagination? at the very least, i think it's an improvement over base64 and even hex!

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi — although point taken, i should consider removing `j` and `v`, especially the latter since it's so often an `A` in trap music titles — so perhaps base46 would be better! are there other letters that should be turfed?

Comment: Many good words contain bad words, so any filter which do not look at context is a bad filter. But try it. i think your problem is the fist part: splitting binary in a sequence of small numbers. -- and to answer your last question: small "L" is like the i. Then you should check the results. The most problems arise with Unicode (so characters in other languages which look like ASCII letters)

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi — also i've found `Q` and `L` could look like vowels too, eg `CQCKYDLCK` but it's getting less plausable and obvious than `cvntbjtch`.. it's hard to decide where to draw the line here

Comment: `256789bcdfghkmnpqrstwxyzBCDFGHJKMNPRSTVWXYZ` here we are at base43 — if we can find one more we can reach 42 

Comment: @ChaseMoskal when you arrive at the set of characters to represent the desired base, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61093432/encode-a-big-integer-to-base62/61852309#61852309 for an algorithm to convert to/from a base...

Comment: @Trentium that is great and will help a lot... i suppose to adapt this to an arbitrary amount of data, i would have to break the data into smaller pieces, which introduces some inefficiency.. i'm interested if there's a different approach that can avoid that inefficiency and produce an optimum result for total amount of data provided

Comment: @ChaseMoskal my apologies, I discovered a flaw in my previous algorithm, as it did not work for cases whereby the target number base was a common denominator of the source number base.  I have deleted my previous answer and am adding another answer that involves chunking, but supplements this with a means to optimize the utilization of the bits and accommodates streaming of data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The challenge with streaming a series of bytes/digits and converting to another base is finding the most efficient ratio of source bytes/digits to target bytes/digits.

To determine the best ratio, the algorithm below contains a function dubbed `mostEfficientChunk()` which takes as parameters the source number base, the target number base, and the maximum source chunk size.  This function then walks the source chunk sizes from 1 to the maximum chunk size, and determines the minimum number of bytes/digits required by the target number base.  Eg, a source of Unit8Array whereby 1 byte ranges from 0 - 255 requires 3 bytes if converting to base 10.  In this example, the efficiency then is measured at 1/3 or 33.33%.  Then a source of 2 bytes is examined, which has a range of 0 - 65535 requiring 5 bytes of base 10, for an efficiency of 2/5 or 40%.  So a source chunk size of 2 bytes when converting from base 256 to base 10 is more efficient than a chunk size of 1 byte.  And so on, until the best ratio is found that is less than or equal to the maximum source chunk size.

The code below dumps the evaluation of `mostEfficientChunk()` to make the determination of the best chunk size readily apparent.

Then, once the chunk size is set, the source data is fed to 'code()' which queues up the source, and then if sufficient data exists to form a chunk, the function converts the chunk to the target base.  Note that `code()` can be called continuously if the source is streaming.  When the stream is finished, `flush()` must be called which appends digits that represent `0` until a chunk size is met, and then produces the final target chunk.  Note that this last chunk is padded, so one will have to track the length of the original source to trim the decoding appropriately.

There are some comments and test cases in the code to help in understanding how the Encoder class operates.

```js
class EncodeStream {

  constructor( fromBase, toBase, encode = 'encode', maxChunkSize = 32 ) {
    console.assert( typeof fromBase === 'string' || typeof fromBase === 'number' );
    console.assert( typeof toBase === 'string' || typeof toBase === 'number' );
    console.assert( encode === 'encode' || encode === 'decode' );
    
    this.encode = encode;
    
    if ( typeof fromBase === 'string' ) {
      this.fromBase = fromBase.length;
      this.fromBaseDigits = fromBase;
    } else {
      this.fromBase = fromBase |0;
      this.fromBaseDigits = null;
    }
    console.assert( 2 <= this.fromBase && this.fromBase <= 2**32 );
    
    if ( typeof toBase === 'string' ) {
      this.toBase = toBase.length;
      this.toBaseDigits = toBase;

    } else {
      this.toBase = toBase |0;
      this.toBaseDigits = null;
    }
    console.assert( 2 <= this.toBase && this.toBase <= 2**32 );
    
    if ( encode === 'encode' ) {
      this.chunking = this.mostEfficientChunk( this.fromBase, this.toBase, maxChunkSize );
    } else {
      let temp = this.mostEfficientChunk( this.toBase, this.fromBase, maxChunkSize );
      this.chunking = {
        bestSrcChunk: temp.bestTgtChunk,
        bestTgtChunk: temp.bestSrcChunk
      };
    }
    
    console.log( `Best Source Chunk Size:  ${this.chunking.bestSrcChunk}, Best Target Chunk Size:  ${this.chunking.bestTgtChunk}` );
    this.streamQueue = [];
  }
  
  code( stream ) {
    console.assert( typeof stream === 'string' || Array.isArray( stream ) );
    
    if ( this.fromBaseDigits ) {
      this.streamQueue.push( ...stream.split( '' ).map( digit => this.fromBaseDigits.indexOf( digit ) ) );
    } else {
      this.streamQueue.push( ...stream );
    }
    
    let result = [];
    while ( this.chunking.bestSrcChunk <= this.streamQueue.length ) {
      // Convert the source chunk to a BigInt value.
      let chunk = this.streamQueue.splice( 0, this.chunking.bestSrcChunk );
      let chunkValue = 0n;
      for ( let i = 0; i < chunk.length; i++ ) {
        chunkValue = chunkValue * BigInt( this.fromBase ) + BigInt( chunk[ i ] );
      }

      // And now convert the BigInt value to a target chunk.
      let temp = new Array( this.chunking.bestTgtChunk - 1 );
      for ( let i = 0; i < this.chunking.bestTgtChunk; i++ ) {
        temp[ this.chunking.bestTgtChunk - 1 - i ] = chunkValue % BigInt( this.toBase );
        chunkValue = chunkValue / BigInt( this.toBase );
      }
      
      result.push( ...temp );
    }
    
    // Finally, if the target base is represented by a string of digits, then map
    // the resulting array to the target digits.
    if ( this.toBaseDigits ) {
      result = result.map( digit => this.toBaseDigits[ digit ] ).join( '' );
    }
    return result;
  }
  
  flush() {
    // Simply add zero digits to the stream until we have a complete chunk.
    if ( 0 < this.streamQueue.length ) {
      while ( this.streamQueue.length < this.chunking.bestSrcChunk ) {
        if ( this.fromBaseDigits ) {
          this.streamQueue.push( this.fromBaseDigits[ 0 ] );
        } else {
          this.streamQueue.push( 0 );
        }
      }
    }
    return this.code( this.fromBaseDigits ? '' : [] );
  }
  
  
  mostEfficientChunk( sourceBase, targetBase, maxChunkSize ) {

    console.assert( 2 <= sourceBase && sourceBase <= 2 ** 32 );
    console.assert( 2 <= targetBase && targetBase <= 2 ** 32 );
    console.assert( 1 <= maxChunkSize && maxChunkSize <= 64 );
    
    // Since BigInt does not have a LOG function, let's just brute force
    // determine the maximum number of target digits per chunk size of
    // source digits...
    let sBase = BigInt( sourceBase );
    let tBase = BigInt( targetBase );
    let mSize = BigInt( maxChunkSize );
    let efficiency = 0;
    let result = { bestSrcChunk: 0, bestTgtChunk: 0 };
    
    for ( let chunkSize = 1n; chunkSize <= mSize; chunkSize++ ) {
      let maxSrcValue = sBase ** chunkSize - 1n;
      let maxSrcBits = maxSrcValue.toString( 2 ).length;
      
      let d = 0n;
      let msv = maxSrcValue;
      while ( 0n < msv ) {
        msv = msv / tBase;
        d++;
      }
      
      if ( this.encode === 'encode' ) {
        console.log( `Source Chunk Size: ${chunkSize}, Max Source Value: ${maxSrcValue}\nTarget Chunk Size: ${d}, Max Target Value: ${tBase**d-1n}, Efficiency: ${Number( chunkSize * 10000n / d ) / 100}%` );
      }
      
      if ( efficiency < Number( chunkSize ) / Number( d ) ) {
        efficiency = Number( chunkSize ) / Number( d );
        result.bestSrcChunk = Number( chunkSize );
        result.bestTgtChunk = Number( d );
      }
    }
   
    return result;
  }


}


let source, toBase, encoder, encoderResult, decoder, decoderResult;

source = [255,254,253,252,251];
toBase = '0123456789';

console.log( '\n\n' );
console.log( [ 'Encoding', source.join(','), `to base '${toBase}'` ] );
encoder = new EncodeStream( 256, toBase, 'encode', 2 );
encoderResult = '';
encoderResult += encoder.code( source );
encoderResult += encoder.flush();
console.log( `Encoded result: '${encoderResult}'` );

console.log( [ 'Decoding...' ] );
decoder = new EncodeStream( toBase, 256, 'decode', 2 );
decoderResult = '';
decoderResult += decoder.code( encoderResult );
decoderResult += decoder.flush();
console.log( `Decoded result: '${decoderResult}'` );

console.log( '\n\n' );
console.log( [ 'Encoding', source.join(','), `to base '${toBase}'` ] );
encoder = new EncodeStream( 256, toBase, 'encode', 16 );
encoderResult = '';
encoderResult += encoder.code( source );
encoderResult += encoder.flush();
console.log( `Encoded result: '${encoderResult}'` );

console.log( [ 'Decoding...' ] );
decoder = new EncodeStream( toBase, 256, 'decode', 16 );
decoderResult = '';
decoderResult += decoder.code( encoderResult );
decoderResult += decoder.flush();
console.log( `Decoded result: '${decoderResult}'` );

source = [255,254,253,252,251,250,249,248,247];
toBase = '256789bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyzBCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXYZ';

console.log( '\n\n' );
console.log( [ 'Encoding', source.join(','), `to base '${toBase}'` ] );
encoder = new EncodeStream( 256, toBase, 'encode', 16 );
encoderResult = '';
encoderResult += encoder.code( source );
encoderResult += encoder.flush();
console.log( `Encoded result: '${encoderResult}'` );

console.log( [ 'Decoding...' ] );
decoder = new EncodeStream( toBase, 256, 'decode', 16 );
decoderResult = '';
decoderResult += decoder.code( encoderResult );
decoderResult += decoder.flush();
console.log( `Decoded result: '${decoderResult}'` );
```

Note that it appears you will need to open up the browser debugger to see the full console log results.

Comment: this look beautiful! for the sake of philosophical completeness, i must ask, since i assume this could run out of memory for gigabytes of data: could this algorithm be adapted to operate on a stream of binary data, whose total size is known ahead of time? i'm imagining a robust algorithm that could produce an ultimately-efficient representation in base-n for any binary data, whether it be tiny, or super large?

Comment: @ChaseMoskal, I updated the answer with a solution that permits streaming of binary data, incrementally producing the desired base N result...  Hopefully I've included enough explanation so that you can understand how it works...

Comment: absolutely brilliant! this is really fantastic! i'm looking forward to integrating this into my systems!